# Jest testing Angular 6 Service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, jestjs

Hello I am kind of stuck here so I decided to open this question,

I am trying to test a service using Jest. But all the test are passing just fine even if they should not.

This is the software version:

Angular v6.0.1
RxJs v6.2.1
Jest v23.1.0

My service looks like this (it should be very simple at this point):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { BaseApiService } from './base-api.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ListsService extends BaseApiService {
  private static readonly LISTS_API = 'http://localhost:3000/lists';
  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super();
  }
  public list(): Observable<BasicList[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<BasicList[]>(ListsService.LISTS_API, BaseApiService.httpOptions)
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
  }
}
```

Actually I do have two test for the same purpose as I am trying to lear how to do the testing without testbed as I read this [article](https://izifortune.com/unit-testing-angular-applications-with-jest/) so this is the test with TestBed:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ListsService } from './lists.service';

const basicListData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name 2"
  }
];

describe('Service: List Service', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let service: ListsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], providers: [ListsService] });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([ListsService, HttpTestingController], (_service, _httpMock) => {
    service = _service;
    httpMock = _httpMock;
  }));

  it('list: should return a sorted list', () => {
    service.list().subscribe(lists => {
      expect(lists.length).toBe(2);
    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/lists');
    req.flush(basicListData);
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

The problem comes with the expect.ToBe(2) expression. As It does not matter at all the number I do write in there. It just thinks it is ok. Even if you just write 1000 or 0. And I know I might be missing something but can not figure it out.

Also this is the same test but without Test Bed:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { ListsService } from './lists.service';

const basicListData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name 2"
  }
];

const provide = (mock: any): any => mock;

describe('Service: Lists', () => {
  let listsService: ListsService;

  const http = { get: jest.fn(() => of(basicListData)) };
  beforeEach(() => {
    listsService = new ListsService(provide(http));
  });

  it('list$: Should return a list of List definitions', () => {
    listsService.list().subscribe(lists => {
      expect(http.get).toBeCalledWith('http://localhost:3000/lists');
      expect(lists.length).toBe(3);
    });
  });
});
```

On this not even the endpoint it is being checked so event a little bit more lost there.

Thanks in advance to any kind of help and I do hope the question is properly explained.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and to solve it I used done.  The test executes before subscribe finishes and done forces it to wait.

```
 it('list$: Should return a list of List definitions', (done) => {
    listsService.list().subscribe(lists => {
      expect(http.get).toBeCalledWith('http://localhost:3000/lists');
      expect(lists.length).toBe(3);

done();

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use an assertion here. Since the operation is async, your tests pass because the case executes before the callback is called. Therefore 'expect' is never called. You could try to return a promise after calling assertion like this:

```
it('list$: Should return a list of List definitions', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return listsService.list().toPromise().then(
      lists => {
        expect(http.get).toBeCalledWith('http://localhost:3000/lists');
        expect(lists.length).toBe(3);
      });
  });
```